# Java 8 Stream groupingBy from Groovy

Tags: groovy, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java 8 Stream API with groovy using `@CompileStatic`:

Writing the `groupingBy` is giving me a headache, the error says:

> groupingBy in java.util.stream.Collectors cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure

Currently using Java 8 and Groovy 2.4.7

My intention is:

1. Use map to build DTOs
2. Use `collect` with `groupingBy` to create a map using the UUIDs as keys

This is the final working code (developed using "Will Lp" and "BalRog" support).

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.Immutable

import java.util.function.Function
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

@CompileStatic
public class ThanksForChecking {

    @Immutable
    public static class Relation {
        String entityUUID
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> rows = [
                [entityUUID: "uuid 1"],
                [entityUUID: "uuid 2"]
        ]

        Map<String, List<Relation>> relations = rows.stream()
                .map { row -> new Relation(row as HashMap) }
                .collect(groupingBy((Function) { Relation r -> return r.entityUUID }))

        println(relations);

        assert relations == [
                "uuid 1": [new Relation(entityUUID: "uuid 1")],
                "uuid 2": [new Relation(entityUUID: "uuid 2")]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `groupingBy` code?

Comment: Is the static groupingBy function from the Java 8 API java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy

Comment: I wrote a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/will-lp/c2cd84f238523d93301d89c3f3eb983b) using your code, but couldn't reproduce your error. Can you point me where I got it wrong?

Comment: Also, what is your groovy and java version?

Comment: Thank you very much Will Lp, thx to your example is now clearer. I have taken your work and edit it to make it match my code and reproduce the error. Currently using Java 8 and Groovy 2.4.7. Surprisingly taking out @CompileStatic makes things work but this is not an option. I'm guessing is probably a problem with the generics that requires some castings to make the magic.

Comment: Try explicitly casting the closure to `Function`. That is, `...collect((java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy((java.util.function.Function){ Relation r -> r.entityUUID }))...`

Comment: Thanks BalRog and Will Lp, that was the last bit. This is my first question and has been solved in 1h. Any way of giving reputation to you two that just commented?

Comment: I'll write my contribution up as an answer. You can do what you wish with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the closure to `Function`, which is the argument type that `Collectors.groupBy()` expects. Change this line:

```
    .collect(groupingBy { Relation r -> return r.entityUUID })
```

To this:

```
    .collect(groupingBy((Function) { Relation r -> return r.entityUUID }))
```

(Remember to import `java.uti‌​l.function.Function`)

Comment: Thx BalRog, this was the last bit needed to make it work!